# How convert this type of date (20160406) to this (2016.04.06) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, date, type-conversion

How convert this type of date (20160406) to this (2016.04.06) in MATLAB? I have a array with first type.

Comment: is it a string to string conversion?

Comment: @Rogalski Primary array is numeric but I think the output should be string. I want save output as a excel file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
a = 20160406
b = num2str(a)
c = strcat(b(1:4), '.', b(5:6), '.', b(7:8))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
data = '20160416'

output = strcat( data(1:4), '.', data(5:6), '.', data(7:8) )
```

Look up strcat and strjoin, they are useful for String manipulation.

Comment: `data` in your snippet is a string. the comment under the question mentioned that it should be numeric.

Comment: Only read the question, not the comments. I see that you've answered it below anyway.